# Entity Framework 4 eager loading not working at all!

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

I am converting linq2sql to entity framework.

During the conversion I needed to convert the loadwith of linq2sql with include for eagar loading, but the eager loading is not working. When I used the profiler, I found that the child entities are loaded with they are accessed.

```
DataBaseEntities context = new V3C_DataBaseEntities();

context.Agents.Include("Account");

Agent ag = context.Agents.Where(x => x.Login_ID == "2").SingleOrDefault(); 

// here the account should have been loaded,
// but actually they are loaded with the line below this is executed.

Console.WriteLine(ag.Account.ID.ToString());
```

If do the following, It works perfectly, but I must do the way mentioned in the question.

```
var c = (from ag in context.Agents.Include("Account")
                     where ag.Login_ID == "2"
                     select ag).SingleOrDefault();
```

I would also like a type safe way of loading child entities.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that as you wrote in question. You **must use include in query**. There is no smooth manner when transforming from Linq2Sql to EF. You must accept new API and use it correctly.

You can use only this:

```
var query = context.Agents.Include("Account");
Agent ag = query.Where(x => x.Login_ID == "2").SingleOrDefault();
```

If you want type safe Include version you must download [Entity Framework Feature CTP5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d) or write your [own extension](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entity-framework-include-with-func-next.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is your query which does not perform the eager load:

```
context.Agents.Include("Account");

Agent ag = context.Agents.Where(x => x.Login_ID == "2").SingleOrDefault();
```

If you change the query to place the `Include` within the expression I believe you will get the results you want.

```
Agent ag = context.Agents
                  .Include("Account")
                  .Where(x => x.Login_ID == "2").SingleOrDefault();
```

In my testing, and I have looked at the resulting generated SQL, the first expression does not join in the related table.  Your `Include` is ignored because it is not part of the query expression.

Comment: hi,as i said this one is working fine , but i have to do the other way , since i have a very big method and that method's datacontext is loaded in depending on the parameters . bottom line is , i have to load the datacontext as defined in the question.

Comment: secondly , please note that i want to convert from linq2sql to entity framework in most smooth manner.